# Where can I find replacement feet for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got a 2009 Unibody MBP, and the feet are starting to fall off.  I've lost one and one I have kept in a safe place.

Does anyone know where I can get replacement feet?  I looked on [Ebay](http://shop.ebay.ca/?_from=R40&_trksid=p3907.m570.l1313&_nkw=macbook+pro+replacement+feet&_sacat=See-All-Categories) to no avail.

**EDIT:**
Well thanks for the answers so far, however nothing is turning up.  I just got off the phone with the Genius bar at the local Apple store, and they said it simply doesn't exist.  They want to sell me an entire "[Lower Case](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Lower-Case/IF163-002)" ... big $$$ for something so trivial.

Still looking for more suggestions.

Comment: Why not try this search : http://shop.ebay.ca/i.html?_kw=macbook&_kw=pro&_kw=feet

Comment: I did, but that search doesn't return anything useful either.

Comment: [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com "ifixit.com") They have just about every part for every modern Mac you need.

Comment: I have the same problem. Too bad Apple doesn't provide a way to address this. Typical.

Comment: The new unibody mac feet are seriously embedded into the thin aluminum. If they are worn a small plastic shim can be affixed but if they are missing, you will have to replace the entire bottom piece or attach a larger adhesive piece rather than mold a new replacement in the part.

Comment: Now that Steve Jobs is no longer, maybe we can see better support for these stupid problems!

Comment: $40 for the part from apple hardly seems big $$$ - have you checked with them recently? (Perhaps the price has dropped lately)

Comment: @bmike They are only glued in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an old Powerbook G3 that had lost 2 of it's rubber feet. Instead of trying to replace them with the same ones, I just went to a hardware store and bought the little rubber stick-on feet that you could put on the bottom of furniture or a TV stand or whatever. Cost all of about 99 cents and worked perfectly.

They looked something like this:

[image]

Comment: probably the only decent answer here.  Apple is fantastic, but stupid stuff like this sure is disappointing.

Comment: This is finally what I did. 8 rubber feet for 2.99 at the local hardware store. They're clear... but meh, it works.

Comment: Yeah, the ones I ended up using weren't the same color as the old Stealth Fighter PowerBook G3 either, but like you say... meh. They worked fine, and how often do you look at the bottom of your laptop anyways? Glad that worked out for you!

Answer (score 3):

I just got back from the Genius bar and actually had the exact same issue.  I had two feet fail, both having different attachment methods.  The foot under the upper left of the keyboard was attached without any adhesive, the foot had plastic "feet" that "snapped" into a black metal piece attached to the bottom case.  The foot under the lower left of the keyboard was attached with adhesive to the outside of the bottom case and further secured with an additional plastic ring running along the inside of the bottom case (this ring broke apart from the foot in addition to the adhesive failing on my machine).

I went to the local Genius bar and the cost of the bottom case ended up being covered by apple care.  Even if apple care had not covered the bottom case, the bottom case was only $38.89.

Comment: That sure would be nice. They're $150 at [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Unibody-Model-No-A1342-Lower-Case/IF160-026)

Comment: Nice trick, think I'll use this before my applecare runs out to get a new bottom case.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a set of 4 replacement feet (along with other Mac replacement parts) at [PowerBook Medic](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/Macbook-Unibody-Feet-Replacement-Black-p-23146.html)

Comment: Oh, that's great.

Answer (score 3):

They sell the set of 4 here. You can also get a single foot.

http://www.pbparts.com/shop.php//0761398.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get some from Apple, I would try there first. Otherwise I do not believe there is an vendor for them.

You could consider molding some foam feet, or custom making your own. Otherwise just deal with it. I've seen several people who either made their own substitute or gone without.

Comment: That's sorta what I'm thinking.  Have to head into the Apple store.

Comment: well thanks for the suggestion, please take a look at the edit in my question.

Comment: Making my own "might" work.  I'm not too keen on going without since there is a hole in the middle that exposes the inside of the notebook.

Comment: @Rock: Stick some electrical tape over it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a few years since I had to replace any of the feet on my laptops (the current ones are pretty well attached), but they used to provide them for free at Apple retail stores if you asked at the Genius Bar. They probably have them now unless they are bonded to the bottom case.

Comment: well thanks for the suggestion, please take a look at the edit in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, if they are only available bonded to the lower case then no one else is likely to have them either.