# How can I make my MacBook Pro screws stop screwing around?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

The title might be a bit misleading, but it's precise: *the screws keep screwing out by themselves*!

It's quite random and I'm not even sure how I've managed to never lose one so far. Most of the times it's the bottom ones who try to run away, some times are the side ones. The top ones, 3 of which are much bigger, never joined the dance and always stayed right where they belong.

What always happens is that I feel them getting out when handling the notebook and then I just screw them back with my nails until I get ahold of a screwdriver. What **I wished to happen** is they simply stay there, keeping the lid in its place as they were meant to be and quit acting up on me!

Anticipating some comments:

- The [screws](http://apple-parts.com/scripts/prodView.asp?idproduct=2918) look all right and fine to the point that doesn't make me think I'd need replacements. This is a behavior I expect more people have with their MBPs so I'm also looking for [shared experiences (the photo shows the same MBP model, by the way)](http://zitseng.com/archives/2838) here. And then again, maybe all I need is replacing them. But do I?
- There are no Genius bars here in Brazil and I'm not willing to go on apple stores searching for [something Apple probably doesn't care about](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/where-can-i-find-replacement-feet-for-my-macbook-pro) <-- I'm looking for practical solutions like the one accepted there. And trying to understand what could be causing this weird issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first time you unscrew the screws on your computer, you'll notice there's some blue gunk around the threads.  That's [Loctite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loctite).  It's essentially a sort of superglue for screws to help them stay in.  The glue adheres the threads to the casing, but isn't strong enough that a decent screwdriver and some wrist action can't break it.  I'd probably recommend finding an appropriate bottle of Loctite and then dabbing a bit on the screws and then screwing them back it.  That should keep the suckers from comin' back out. :)  I'm not sure about prices in Brazil, but in the US a bottle of Loctite (or something similar) should only cost you a few dollars.

Comment: Wow, perfect! I'll look into that. I've noticed the blue gunk, of course, but never even wondered on giving more thought about it! - "Superbonder", now I see is the loctite's final consumer's product, is very well known at least around here. But looks like I should seek the industrial version. I'll bring an update once I get to try it! :)

Comment: As a follow up question, *would you happen to know exactly why that's needed on those screws?* I don't see any glue being used in almost every other screw I''ve tried from many other gadgets and electronics.

Comment: @Cawas - It's not needed on screws going into plastic, and often left out on cheap products. Also, there are a number of alternatives to locktite, and it also does not have to have a color, so the screws *could* have a locktite-like compound on them, and it's just not visible. Alternatively, the locktite could be applied from the inside, if the device assembly order allows it, or there could be a lock-washer or other hardware involved. Also, some screw thread profiles do not require locktite, at the expense of repeated removal and re-insertion damaging the threads.

Comment: Actualy it's a Threadlocker or Thread locking fluid and Loctite is the company which pioneered the product.

Comment: Thanks @Fake. I've also read somewhere that the screws on the mac screw out due to tremor, bouncing or even handling the notebook somehow. In my sick mind I was thinking about magnetism or static electricity, because the later one I do feel on its metallic cover. Anyways, good insight!

Comment: @mspasov oh yeah, almost like the *post-it*, which is actually a *stationery with a re-adherable strip of adhesive on the back*. But we all agree in using the shorter branded name due to convenience! Still, I'm having a hard time finding the **Loctite 243**, which seems to be the one I need, even though it appears on the front-page image before going into the ["industrial" site](http://www.loctite.com/index2.php?cc=br). Maybe I should look for the unbranded name in this case...

Comment: @Cawas Amazon.com has it (of course) though the shipping costs would probably be much more expensive than the actual glue.

Comment: @mspasov  - Locktite is the Kleenex of threadlockers. Sure there is a specific name for it, but locktite has become s genericized it pretty much means the same thing as threadlocker.

Comment: @Cawas make sure you pick up purple or blue. Also if you buy new screws, they will be pre-glued with thread-locker.

Comment: Dave, yup. Probably not doing amazon in this case! :P @mspasov any special reasons on purple or blue other than looking like a teletubie?

Comment: @Cawas Usualy red means permanent (high strength) lock, blue is medium and purple is low. It's described in the [Threadlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-locking_fluid) article and you can also draw this conclusion by searching the net. Don't go red - I use it on my motorcycle engine, it's overkill.